# Largest Integer in ARM assembly

Tags: arrays, integer, arm

This is a homework question, but I'm stuck.

The assignment is to find the largest integer in an array.  Here's the C code we're given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int mybig( int array[] ) ;

void main( char * argv[], int argc )
{
int array[] = { 5, 15, 100, 25, 50, -1 } ;

int biggest ;

biggest = mybig( array ) ;

printf( "Biggest integer in array: %d\n", biggest ) ;

}
```

I've made about a dozen versions of the assembly so far, but this is the closest I've gotten

```
.global mybig
 mybig:  stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
    mvn v1, #0
 loop:  ldrb a4, [a1], #4
    MOVLT a4, a1
    cmp a1, v1
    bne loop
    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
    .end
```

Every time I link it together, I hit an infinite loop, and I'm not sure why.  Any help would be majorly appreciated, the professor didn't teach us anything in an introductory course, just told us to do it, and gave us a link to a toolchain to compile and assemble.

EDIT: This is where I've gotten to.  Program doesn't run, just hits an infinite loop.

```
    .global mybig
mybig:  stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
    mvn v1, #0
    mov a3, a1
loop:   ldr a4, [a1], #4
    cmp a4, a1
    MOVMI a3, a1
    cmp a1, v1
    bne loop
    mov a1, a4
    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
    .end
```

C code hasn't changed

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with this.

Comment: Can you give me some kind of clue to go on?  I'm lost.

Comment: 1.) You're using ldrb, which loads BYTES not WORDS. 2.) There is no need to push any register on the stack, because you can freely use a1-a4 and ip for temporary storage. To go back to the caller you can use bx lr. 3.) You are not comparing the value you load with your current highest value. Just with -1, which is probably supposed to be the end-marker. But that check also fails because of the ldrb.

Comment: I changed the ldrb to an ldr, and it worked for three run cycles, then it started having the same issue.  Infinite loop.

The negative one is indeed an end-marker, but what did you mean about pushing registers?  Can you give me a specific syntax when this happened?  My instructor threw us to the wolves so to speak, and I honestly don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: `.global mybig  
 
mybig:  stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}  
 mvn a3, #0  
loop: ldr a4, [a1], #4  
 cmp a4, a1  
 MOVMI a4, a1  
 cmp a1, a3  
 bne loop  
 mov a1, a4  
 ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}  
 .end`

None of the formatting for the code is working for some reason in the comments.  This is where I'm at right now.

Comment: @user1772735 please click "edit" below your question and add code there, not to a comment.

Comment: @DourHighArch sorry about that, added up top

Comment: you should accept your answers or provide comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be my solution:

```
.global mybig
 mybig:
   // a1 = Highest word, defaults to 0x80000000 = −2,147,483,648
   // a2 = Pointer to array
   // a3 = current word
    mov a2, a1
    mov a1, #0x80000000
 .Lloop:
    ldr   a3, [a2], #4 // Load word and advance pointer by 4 bytes
    cmn   a3, #1       // Compare with -1
    bxeq  lr           // Return if endmarker was found
    cmp   a1, a3       // Compare current highest word and new word
    movlt a1, a3       // Replace highest word if it was smaller
    b     .Lloop       // Loop again
    .end
```

While this is not the best possible code in regards of performance it should be self explaining.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the comments.  I understand what I did wrong, and I'll formulate my own answers so I don't plagiarize your solution.